# How to download a file on FTP by using Python

Tags: python, urllib, ftplib, filezilla

I'm trying to download a couple of files (csv, pdf, ..) on a FTP server by using a Python library called [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html).

I made this code who unfortunately doesn't word since I'm getting an error.

#### CODE :

```
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlretrieve('ftp://user_name:password@host_name:port_number/users/appli/gedftp/data/BO/LME/TEST_CSV_INTE.csv', 'file')
```

#### ERROR :

> URLError: <urlopen error ftp error: error_perm('550
> users/appli/gedftp/data/BO/LME: No such file or directory.')>

Yet, in [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), I can see that the directory/file exists.

[image]

Here is .xml configuration of the FTP server in FileZilla (I didn't put the real info) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<FileZilla3>
    <Servers>        
        <Server>
            <Host>host_name</Host>
            <Port>port_number</Port>
            <Protocol>0</Protocol>
            <Type>0</Type>
            <User>gedftp</User>
            <Pass>password</Pass>
            <Account>test</Account>
            <Logontype>4</Logontype>
            <TimezoneOffset>0</TimezoneOffset>
            <PasvMode>MODE_DEFAULT</PasvMode>
            <MaximumMultipleConnections>0</MaximumMultipleConnections>
            <EncodingType>Auto</EncodingType>
            <BypassProxy>0</BypassProxy>
            <Name>server_name</Name>
            <Comments />
            <LocalDir />
            <RemoteDir />
            <SyncBrowsing>0</SyncBrowsing>server_name&#x0A;        
        </Server>
            </Servers>
</FileZilla3>
```

#### EDIT :

I get the same problem with [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) :

```
import ftplib

FTP_HOST = "host_name"
FTP_USER = "gedftp"
FTP_PASS = "password"

ftp = ftplib.FTP(FTP_HOST, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS)
ftp.encoding = "utf-8"

filename = "/users/appli/gedftp/data/BO/LME/TEST_CSV_INTE.csv"
 
with open(filename, "rb") as file:
    # Command for Uploading the file "STOR filename"
    ftp.storbinary(f"STOR {filename}", file)
```

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/users/appli/gedftp/data/BO/LME/TEST_CSV_INTE.csv'

Do you have any idea how to fix this or any other proposition ?

Comment: Is there a home directory in FileZilla ? If so, maybe you can try to append it as a prefix to your path

Comment: The directory that gives FileZilla for the file is `ftp://gedftp@host_name/users/appli/gedftp/data/BO/LME/TEST_CSV_INTE.csv`

Comment: From your error message, it seems it managed to contact the ftp server but can't get the file at the path you pointed. Can you try again with a file in the root directory ?

Comment: Thanks @John. I'm trying right now to open a file in the root directory `/` but still the same error in Python.

Comment: Given the fact that the second piece of code runs on your local computer and not on the FTP server, do you have the file `/users/appli/gedftp/data/BO/LME/TEST_CSV_INTE.csv` on your computer (not the FTP server)? If I understand the error correctly, it couldn't find it on your machine

Comment: Thank you so much @Guy. This is the problem. I was trying to access a local file. Actually, I needed to specify the working directory on the server using `ftp.cwd('/users/appli/gedftp/data/BO/LME')`. Can you add an answer to my post ?

Comment: Sure, added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in the comment, it seems that you have used the file path `/users/appli/gedftp/data/BO/LME/TEST_CSV_INTE.csv` in your local code and trying to open it on your local machine, while you were actually referencing a file which is located on server.

That's why opening the file locally failed :)